# could not launch vCenter vSphere client

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I just installed vCenter on an ESXI host (v7.0 U3):

- (my storage is only 256GB, so I choose "thin" mode)
- It seems that "vSphere client service" is healthy.
  [image]
- And I can see linking page for vSphere client
  [image]
- But the vSphere client could never be launched
  [image]

Anybody knows why? Thanks!

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue. But it noticed that your second screenshot shows a IP address while the third shows a hostname. Check if the DNS record points at the correct IP address.

Comment: Thanks Gerald: it is DNS problem. I added IP/FQDN to local etc/hosts, and now it works!

Comment: Great! I turned my comment into an answer, so you can accept it. Otherwise the question will stay in the system forever as unsolved. You should also accept the answer on your other question.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, how to turn your-comment to be an answer?

Comment: Okay Gerald, I see what you meant: just accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your second screenshot shows an IP address while the third shows a hostname. Check if the DNS record points at the correct IP address.